ESP32 Arduino IDE and publishing .BIN files
I would like to distribute a BIN file for code that I have written for the ESP32 using the Arduino IDE. When I upload the compiled code I can see the IDE issuing the command:
esptool.exe --chip esp32 --port COM5 --baud 921600 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode keep --flash_freq keep --flash_size keep
0x1000 X.ino.bootloader.bin
0x8000 X.ino.partitions.bin
0xe000 boot_app0.bin
0x10000 X.ino.bin
So, for my project X there are 4 bin files.
If I use the IDE "Export Compiled Binary" option then I get one BIN file X.ino.esp32.bin.
My question is if I want to distribute enough for a person to buy a given EDP32 module, use the esptool.exe to install the software then what .BIN files do I actually need?
Do I need all four with the long esptool.exe command above or can I get away with just the X.ino.esp32.bin file and a shorter command line? If so what would that command line look like?
Many thanks for any help / guidance you can give me on this?
Martin

A great way to discover this yourself is to try it :) If you're going to distribute this and expect other people to use it, going through the process yourself will help you document the process.

On your developer pc you need to merge all 4 bin files into one .bin file.
This can be achieved in two ways:
or to use github.com/vtunr/esp32_binary_merger
or to use (built-in esptool functionality, i would use this)
esptool merge_bin command

On the customer pc, you may install esptool and use write_flash command, but easier way just to install Flash Download Tool from espressif tools.
Keep in mind, your start address for flashing will be 0x0000

Hi, many thanks for getting back to me on this one. I'll give that a try. I was playing yesterday and used the esptool read_flash 0 ALL flash_contents.bin options followed by write_flash 0x0 flash_contents.bin which seemed to do the trick too. Many thanks once again for your help. Martin
